# How to grab a certain data from Array?

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to Javascript / Ionic so I try to wrap my head around different concepts.

I have a function that retrieve the users like this :

```
$timeout(function(){
              $scope.users = snapshot1.val();
              console.log($scope.users);
              })
```

Which gives me the information in the console.

Now, I would like to isolate the field "name" but when I do :

```
snapshot1.val().name;
```

It does **not** work. Is there a way to grab only a specific field ?

Comment: Have you tried using the set $scope, so users.name

Comment: Hello, I have no problem writting {{user.name}} in my DOM, what I want is on the JS side to store it but it doesn't grab it when I try elementById, it returns null even if it displays on the DOM...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
console.log(snapshot1.val().map(el=>el.name));
```

If its really an Array, you can generate a new Array containing just the name property using Array.prototype.map...

Comment: You should note that the shorter syntax to define anonymous functions, known as the “fat arrow” is only supported in ES2015 (or ES6) syntax.

Comment: Hello yes it retrieves an error, I already tried : `TypeError: snapshot1.val(...).map is not a function`